# Inconsistency with Prettier on local vs prod on the same Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

**Problem:** There seems to be a mismatch in how the prettier parser performs in my local environment vs Production environment when I host my React application. The issue is particularly for the "in" keyword.

**Actual behavior:**
**production env**
[image]

You may try it yourself.

`let isFunctionCall = (object) => {   return "FunctionCall" in object; };`

Copy paste the following code in the code editor [here](https://query-api-react.vercel.app/create-new-indexer?accountId=roshaan.near) and then click the **Format** button. It should throw an error. Now, clone and start [my repo](https://github.com/roshaans/query-api-react) on your local setup and head to `http://localhost:3000/create-new-indexer?accountId=Roshaan.near` and input the same code and it should work without any problems. I have made sure the production env is running the latest code.

Code snippet that is responsible for running prettier:

```js
       
          const formattedCode = prettier.format(indexingCode, {
            parser: "babel",
            plugins: [parserBabel],
          });
```

What can be the issue here?

**Environments:**

- Prettier Version: 2.8.4
- Running Prettier via:  Javascript package:  `"prettier": "^2.7.1"`,-->
- Runtime Chrome browser
- Prettier plugins: prettier/parserBabel

**Expected behavior:** Formatting works as expected on javascript code in my local environment while developing the application. And I expect it to work in the production environment without any hiccups and for the most part it does, expect it does not like the "in" keyword.

Comment: Why do you care how the code is formatted on production?

Comment: Side note: unsure why you would be using `let` to define that method.